# No fields to select

Tags: 7, entities, views

In View 3, the contextual filter page is missing some fields; only content, content revision, content translation, file usage, global, search, and user show up. Is this an installation issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Tutorials for Drupal 7 show how to use Contextual Filters using Fields, but fields are called Content in the current versions of Drupal7 / Views 3.